# SingleResult Web Api remove Queryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iqueryable

I've been  trying to access my object `<User>` by using `SingleResult.Create()`.

The issue here is that my API is returning a wrapped object containing [1] element.

```
{"Queryable":[{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","UserName":"JohnDoe","Id":1}]}
```

When using `SingleResult<T>`, I've seen that is possible to return 1 single element of a type like this:

```
{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","UserName":"JohnDoe","Id":1}
```

I would like to remove `{"Queryable":[]}` from my  `SingleResult<T>`

Please Help :D

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Don't vandalize your question and invalidate existing answers.

Comment: I want to remove my code, i shouldn't had done that. It was a mistake.    

I am personally affected by this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `SingleResult.Create()` is creating a wrapper object for your entity, where what you SEEM to want is the entity itself.  Either use another method internal to your project that doesn't wrap your object (no idea what that would be), or change the signature of your method and return the entity directly.

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual TEntity GetById(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var data = GetDataById(id);
        return data; 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}

public virtual TEntity GetbyId(int id)
{
    var data = _ctx.Set<TEntity>().Where(e => e.Id == id);
    var entity = data.FirstOrDefault();
    return entity;
}
```